# Ansible json_query how to remove square bracket & double quote

Tags: ansible, json-query

I want to filter this variable hp but it getting print as square bracket with `""`.
how do i remove square bracket with `""` just to get the only value. can someone please help here ?
I was looking as regex but not able to find the exact syntax.

```
srv_make1: '{{ basic_params | from_json | json_query("servers.server_details[*].srv_make") }}'
```

Thanks

Comment: pls add current output and expected output in your question

Comment: this is my current output:

Comment: ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "hp"
    ]
}

Comment: but i want  srv_make1: hp

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar.
Was getting

```
["abc"]
```

to overcome it, had to do 2 things:

- append `| [0]` to the json query
- use replace to get rid of `"`

so in your case instead of

```
srv_make1: '{{ basic_params | from_json | json_query("servers.server_details[*].srv_make") }}'
```

it will look something like

```
srv_make1: '{{ basic_params | from_json | json_query("servers.server_details[*].srv_make | [0]") | replace('\"','') }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"How to remove square bracket & double quote?"*

[`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) always returns a list. It depends on the `debug` task how a list is displayed. For example

```
  vars:
    srv_make1: [a,b,c]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: srv_make1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ srv_make1|to_yaml }}"
```

give

```
TASK [debug] ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "srv_make1": [
        "a", 
        "b", 
        "c"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "[a, b, c]\n"
}
```

It's possible to use `template` and write the list into a file without brackets and quotes. For example the template

```
shell> cat srv_make1.conf.j2
{% for item in srv_make1 %}{{ item }} {% endfor %}
```

with the task

```
    - template:
        src: srv_make1.conf.j2
        dest: srv_make1.conf
```

gives

```
shell> cat srv_make1.conf
a b c
```

Comment: but i have requirement actually i have variable template file and that looks like

Comment: srv_make1: '{{ basic_params | from_json | json_query("servers.server_details[*].srv_make") }}'

Comment: so basically when i am passing the json then i am getting value from json_query is